# Add StateMachine object in concurrent container

Tags: ros-kinetic, smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings,

I am currently trying to write a state machine with smach for a robot, including a safety fuction, where the activity of the robot should be preempted, once a specific message is sent to a certain topic. I tried to modify the example using monitor state and concurrent container: http://wiki.ros.org/mysmach/Tutorials/State%20Machine%20Preemption%20with%20MonitorState. My idea was to replace the FOO_CALC state with the state machine of my robot, that is nested in the concurrent container. My code reads as the following: https://github.com/Mrkeyiiii/ROS_Learning/blob/master/example0/src/safety.py

After rosrun one would get the following message: TypeError: 'StateMachine' object is not callable.  I wonder whether there is any work-around for this problem?

PS: It's my first time to ask a question in this platform and I am not sure whether I am doing it correctly. Please let me know if there is anything that I could improve. Many thanks in advance!

Edited: Added error code:

```
[ERROR] [1552331031.713732]: Error raised during SMACH container construction: 
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/qi/catkin_ws/src/example0/src/safety.py", line 134, in main
    smach.Concurrence.add('FOO_CALC', sm_sub())
TypeError: 'StateMachine' object is not callable

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/qi/catkin_ws/src/example0/src/safety.py", line 150, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/qi/catkin_ws/src/example0/src/safety.py", line 134, in main
    smach.Concurrence.add('FOO_CALC', sm_sub())
TypeError: 'StateMachine' object is not callable
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318129/add-statemachine-object-in-concurrent-container/) by [KeyKeyQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/40405/keykeyq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-03-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-03-10**:
Can you please update your question with a copy and paste of the full error and your code?

**Comment by [KeyKeyQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/40405/keykeyq/) on 2019-03-11**:
Hi, thanks for your reply, please check the updated question :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have code like this

```
sm_sub = smach.StateMachine(outcomes=['foo_succeeded','preempted']) # line 119
```

Here, `sm_sub` is an *object* and the interpreter is telling you that you can't call an object in the following error you posted

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/qi/catkin_ws/src/example0/src/safety.py", line 134, in main
    smach.Concurrence.add('FOO_CALC', sm_sub())
TypeError: 'StateMachine' object is not callable
```

In line 134, you're trying to call the `sm_sub` object, which the interpreter is saying you can't do:

```
smach.Concurrence.add('FOO_CALC', sm_sub()) # parentheses means you're calling a function
```

In the example that you linked to, I'm guessing that you're following this line

```
smach.Concurrence.add('FOO_CALC', foo())
```

Here, the author went against Python's conventions and named their *class* `foo` instead of `Foo` (notice the lack of a capital F in the first one). This can make things a little confusing if you're not reading carefully. The example is actually simultaneously creating an object of `foo` type and passing it to the `add` function.

So, what you probably need to do is pass the *object* `sm_sub` and not call it.

Try

```
smach.Concurrence.add('FOO_CALC', sm_sub) # no parentheses on sm_sub
```

instead and see if it works. Please note that I'm not familiar with this package, I'm just going off of the tutorial that you linked to, your posted error, and your posted code.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2019-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-03-11**:
I'd also suggest that you probably want to stick to [Python's conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) of using caps for classes (and no underscores) and snake case for everything else. This makes it easier for others to read your code and for you later when you go back and have to change things.

**Comment by [KeyKeyQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/40405/keykeyq/) on 2019-03-12**:
you are totally right - I passed the object and it actually worked like I expected. Also thanks for your suggestion - the conventions appear to be very helpful for a newbie like me :D.